# Eclipse não funcionar acentuação

Tags: eclipse

Já selecionei todos as configurações possíveis para UTF-8 porém os resultados no terminal com acentuação da erro, não sei se é versão do Eclipse.

Observação: Versão instalada é a última.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quando você chama a JVM, ela pega o _charset encoding_ do ambiente Windows, que é diferente de UTF-8. Tem que passar o _encoding_ certo para a JVM. Clique com o botão direito na classe `Primero.java`, selecione `Run As > Run Configurations...`, vá na aba `Arguments`, `VM Arguments`, e insira o _encoding_ apropriado: `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8`. Alternativamente, configure para usar o _encoding_ do Windows nos arquivos-fontes (pegar do ambiente) e remova o que foi configurado nos argumentos da VM.

Answer (score -2):

[Abrir imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bskM3.png) o meu eclipse estava com o mesmo problema e consegui resolver da seguinte forma
no menu run > run configurations... > common e coloquei na opção: use system encoding (windows-1252).